# I need help refreshing a grid that is generated by a custom application

Tags: jquery, angular

I am using a system that uses angular to generate these objects that we can use to make apps, but it is not very customizable and I've found myself having to override things using jquery.

So this one that is not working for me is like this:

```
<div id='blahblahblah' 
     class='blahblahblah' 
     role='presentation' 
     ui-grid-one-bind-id='1-grid-container' 
     ng-style='{blahblah}' 
     bind-scroll-vertical="true">
```

If I use inspector and edit the HTML and remove bind-scroll-vertical, the div seems to update and the scrolling starts working. If I do something like this:

`$('#blahblahblah').removeAttr('bind-scroll-vertical');`

The attribute disappears but the scrolling does not start working correctly. So I'm thinking some kind of refresh or update on the div needs to occur.

`angular.element($('#blahblahblah')).triggerHandler('change')` doesn't seem to work, others suggested updating the width, or using focus().blur(). Those seem to not work either.

Does anyone have any idea, understanding I don't have access to change the angular code generation?

Comment: @PatrickHume the questioner says they don't have access to the Angular source code.

Comment: yep my bad  I didn't read the question fully...have you tried calling the jquery scroll to trigger the scroll after removing the attribute ```  $( "#target" ).scroll(); ``` ?